# Bits per channel in Python

Tags: python, image, photoshop

In Photoshop I can find the number of bits per channel of an image with:

```
// BitsPerChannelType
var bits = app.activeDocument.bitsPerChannel
```

What is the Pythonic equivalent to this and what modules are needed?

bits = ??? # where the returned result is 8, 16 or 24

Comment: look at `PIL` or `opencv` libs

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest even once you've chosen a library it's not straightforward.  Here's the guidance for PIL: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html

Answer (score 2):

There's not really a standard way, AFAIK. I think the nearest you will come is with `exiftool`.

Here I get some of the more likely candidates you might use to work out whatever it is you really want to know:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# !pip3 install PyExifTool

files = ['png8.png' , 'png24.png', 'png48.png', 'normal.jpg', 'mad.jpg', 'file.tif']
tags  = ['BitDepth', 'BitsPerSample']


from exiftool import ExifToolHelper
with ExifToolHelper() as et:
    for d in et.get_tags(files, tags=tags):
        for k, v in d.items():
            print(f"Dict: {k} = {v}")
```

**Sample Output**

```
Dict: SourceFile = png8.png
Dict: PNG:BitDepth = 8
Dict: SourceFile = png24.png
Dict: PNG:BitDepth = 8
Dict: SourceFile = png48.png
Dict: PNG:BitDepth = 16
Dict: SourceFile = normal.jpg
Dict: File:BitsPerSample = 8
Dict: SourceFile = mad.jpg
Dict: File:BitsPerSample = 12
Dict: SourceFile = file.tif
Dict: EXIF:BitsPerSample = 32 32 32
```

Bear in mind that some images, like the `png8.png` above are palette images, some, like the TIF image are float values and so on.

---

Note that you can get often quite a bit of potentially useful info just using `file-magic`. For example, it detects that my `mad.jpg` is 12-bit:

```
import magic
print(magic.detect_from_filename('mad.jpg'))

FileMagic(mime_type='image/jpeg', encoding='binary', name='JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, extended sequential, precision 12, 227x149, components 3')
```