# TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: MagickCore::ResolutionType

Tags: python, imagemagick, pythonmagick

The following code:

```
import subprocess
import PythonMagick
subprocess.run(["convert","rose:","test.pnm"])
print(PythonMagick.Image("test.pnm").resolutionUnits())
```

produces the error: `TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: MagickCore::ResolutionType`

How can I get the resolution units of an image using PythonMagick?

Comment: Why do you convert to PNM format first - given that PNM format is unable to store/contain any resolution information?

Comment: I want to be able to get the information for images of any format. I just picked one at random for the MRE.

Comment: If you want to retain all information, in general, use MIFF format as it is most expressive.

Comment: Assuming the basic problem is a bug, I've raised an issue: https://github.com/ImageMagick/PythonMagick/issues/22

Answer (score 1):

You can more succinctly extract x-resolution (dpi) like this:

```
magick image.png -format "%x" info:
```

If you want x-resolution, y-resolution and their units, use:

```
magick image.png -format "%x %y %U" info:
```

---

`exiftool` may be a lighter-weight dependency, see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75276756/2836621).

Comment: Thanks. Certainly not quite as foul as `identify -verbose`, but I'd still like an answer that doesn't require `subprocess`.

Comment: Did you try the *"file magic"* part of the linked answer with an image that actually contains x-resolution?

Comment: `exiftool` is Perl, so I'm not sure it is lighter-weight than ImageMagick.

Comment: Interestingly, for the following image: `convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 xc:white test.jpg` `magic` returns `resolution (DPI), density 300x300`, and for `convert -units PixelsPerCentimeter -density 300 xc:white test.jpg`, `resolution (DPCM), density 300x300`, so this looks like the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a foul hack and doesn't really answer my question:

```
import subprocess
import PythonMagick
subprocess.run(["convert","rose:","test.pnm"])
# print(PythonMagick.Image("test.pnm").resolutionUnits())
spo = subprocess.run(["identify","-verbose","test.pnm"], capture_output=True, text=True)
for line in spo.stdout.splitlines():
    values = line.split(":")
    if len(values) == 2:
        key, value = values
        if key.strip() == "Units":
            print(value.strip())
```

I'd love a better answer.